# MATLAB using rand to test for time invariance

Tags: matlab, time, signal-processing

So I am given a certain system: `y(n) = 10x(n)cos(0.25pi*n + 0.1pi)`

And I am to test if the system is time invariant by plotting two input signals x(n) and x(n-2), and their corresponding output signals. X(n) is supposed to be a causal signal with 10 elements using the rand function.

This is the code I've written thus far:

```
clear all; clc; close all;
n = 0:9; n2 = 0:11;                        
xN1 = [rand(1,10) 0 0];                   %x(n)
xN2 = [0 0 rand(1,10)];                   %x(n-2)
yN1 = 10.*xN1.*cos(0.25.*pi.*n2+0.1.*pi); %y(n)
yN2 = 10.*xN2.*cos(0.25.*pi.*n2+0.1.*pi); %y(n-2)

figure, 
subplot(2,2,1)
    stem(n2,xN1),title('x1')
subplot(2,2,2)
    stem(n2,yN1),title('y1')
subplot(2,2,3)
    stem(n2,xN2),title('x2')
subplot(2,2,4)
    stem(n2,yN2),title('y2')
```

My question is what am I being asked to plot? x1 vs. x2, and then y1 vs. y2? Or x1 vs. n and x2 vs. n, and so on.

This is the result I obtain with my current code, https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrcRV.jpg. Does this mean the signal is time variant?

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system#Formal_example) example on Wiki explains it nicely. By the way, you are not delaying the signals, they are two different signals since output of `rand` is different (or random) every time, unless you specify the seed. So you should store result of `rand` in a variable first and use that to create `xN1` and `xN2`.

Answer (score 0):

No, There is a very problem with your code. To prove that the system is time invariant we have to delay the input first and get the output and then delay the output for the same input and see whether both inputs are the same you are taking `rand()` which changes the input for y1 and y2 so you can never see if the system is time invariant 
Here is an example for Time invariant system :

```
n0 = 1;                 %delay
n = 0:0.1:1;
x1 = [zeros(1,n0) cos(n)]%delaying the input
y1 = 2.5*x1;
x2 = [cos(n)]
y2 = [zeros(1,n0) 2.5*x2]%delaying the ouput
subplot(2,1,1)
stem(1:length(n) + 1,y1)
title('DELAYED INPUT')
subplot(2,1,2)
stem(1:length(n) + 1,y2)
title('DELAYED OUTPUT')
```

[image]

You can observe that the input remains the same just delayed in the input for the first time and the output is delayed for the second time but the output remains the same.
Plus one more thing your input is not time dependent xn1 and xn2 are not time dependent